# Using VBA to password protect automated reports

Tags: excel, vba, passwords

**Situation:**
So im trying to make something as follows, There is a VBA that automates reports for multiple people.
However i do not want User 1 to be able to generate User 2's report.

My solution is to add in an Input box to ask for User 1's Name, this then checks if the name is on a list, if the name exists then asks for a password, if password and User match, then the report is generated.

**How It Works:**
I have planned this out so that in a hidden sheet: Sheet X

Sheet X holds a table of Username - Password.

The table is called PasswordTable.

The data in the Username column is in a named range called Username.

The data in the Password column is in a named ranged called Pass.

The VBA then does a lookup against this input to see if there is a match in the table, and will then continue with the rest of the macro.

```
Dim Password As Value
Dim Choice As String
Dim Lookup As Sring

Choice = InputBox("Whose Report would you like to view")
If Choice = ("Username") 'Username is from the named range
        Password = InputBox("What is your password?")
        Lookup = Vlookup(Choice, PasswordTable, 2, False)
        If Password <> Lookup 'Looks up the Username input against the password for that user
            Print ("Incorrect Password")
        Else
            Do the rest of the VBA
Else
    Print ("You do not have access to see Reports")
```

This is my working in a mix of VBA and Psuedocode, so please bear with me on the mix of syntax.

Please do not reply with hardcoded VBA passwords as i have decided against this, my future plan is to hash the password table and have the VBA de-hash it.

Thanks In Advance :D .

Comment: You have explained what you are doing but i don't see what your issue is?

Comment: If you can write VBA, then don't mix it in with pseudocode - just write the VBA and run it, then tell us what's not working and in what way it doesn't work.  BTW - "my future plan is to hash the password table and have the VBA de-hash it": there is no "dehash" process for passwords (or if there is, you've done it wrong).  You hash the supplied password and compare it to the table of already-hashed passwords.  Still, that's all wasted effort if you're using Excel, since the entire process is easily bypassed by anyone who can use Google and cares to try.

Comment: That said....   Use `Application.Vlookup(userName, tableRange, 2, false)` to try to retreive the user's password.  If the return value is an error then the username was not found, otherwise ask the user for the password and see if it match the value you got from the vlookup.